# How to host a Windows executable on Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I have a Windows executable that I would like to host on Google cloud so that users can access it from any internet-connected device at any time.

Which service would be best for me to do this?

I thought the "App Engine" would be best, but it seems to be telling me that I should use a certain programming language for the API, but I have already compiled the program (using C++, not listed for Google App Engine).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this is to leverage [Citrix Virtual Apps & Desktop](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-virtual-apps-desktops-service/install-configure/resource-location/google.html). Create a VM on GCE and utilize Citrix Apps & Desktop. Use a remote desktop client to access the windows VM for management purposes.

Comment: A bit complicated way. How about just using a hosting provider who support Windows server? Like for instance https://TransIP.eu/. The alternate solution: Make your WinApp a DotCore project. They can be compiled to run native in Linux environment.